# Is there recourse to a user making persistent trivial edits?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

[This user](https://serverfault.com/users/2321/warren) is repeatedly spamming the front page making trivial edits like [this](https://serverfault.com/posts/305722/revisions). I'm assuming he's just "farming" the Copy Editor badge, but it's unnecessary and annoying. Can a mod slap him on the wrist? Is there anything that *normal* plebs without a diamond can do to tell him to cut it out? Commenting on things that he edits doesn't seem appropriate, since they're not his questions.

Also, in a related note, does rolling back someone's edits remove the rolled-back post from a user's edit count for the purpose of *Strunk & White* and *Copy Editor*?

---

On further review, it doesn't look like he has a history of horrible edits, he just has a recent string of crappy ones. It's still rather annoying, though.

Comment: Shock therapy. Make them look at pictures of bad cabling jobs.

Comment: @voretaq7 - I like looking at pictures of bad cabling jobs. Makes me feel better about my mediocre jobs, and I've got a new building with 284 ports in the coming weeks that need to be patched up and it encourages me to make it looks spiffy ;)

Comment: @Mark http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g190/mrmaigo/1211601771869.jpg Perfect, except I'd have to put my foot in someone's hind-end for using zip ties.

Comment: Yeah the zip ties make that worse than no ties at all. At least then you can actually replace a cable or dress a new one in.

Comment: Well, I think the chances of needing to replace a cable in that setup is debatable. How often do you replace cables when you've got 100% of your avaliable ports patched? (plus, we don't know where those cables are going, maybe they're only travelling to the next rack over). The biggest issue in that pic for me is that they didn't cut the excess off the zip ties. That's just sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutally right on the first point. That is totally un-nessesary, but unfortunately there's not much we can do except email them. Which I shall do now.

Answer (score 6):

Someone should probably tell him that edits of less than 6 characters don't count toward Copy Editor.

Comment: Good point actually