# How to address a user who inappropriately edited an accepted answer

Tags: discussion

I'm not going to provide the example because I'm not here to start a flamewar over someone being an overly aggressive user.

However, in the case that another user goes in and starts making edits to an accepted answer what should we do? We don't really have a method to directly contact the user and ask them what their reason was.

Please note, this is separate from [this](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2275/is-there-recourse-to-a-user-making-persistent-trivial-edits). My specific situation is someone thought they were being helpful but didn't bother reading all of the information and then without comment made edits to an accepted answer. I was not asked if I wanted to accept the edits, so I went back and edited it again and added why their edit was unnecessary in the comments.

Comment: There are far too many variables at play here for us to answer without seeing the question you're referring to. Please link it.

Comment: If this concerns your last revision from today, you just move on - there is no need to have a second thought about this, let alone post here. Also, frankly I consider the edit an improvement, not because  your post actually was rude, but because it could appear so to the casual viewer.

Comment: The edit chain is not that bad, as such you added an '@' to let know it's to tag an username in the end. For the last part of your question please see there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179257/what-happen-if-other-users-make-edit-on-someones-answer/179259#179259 for edit notification. An answerer will get notified to review only if the editor got less than 2k points, and you might miss the review approval if the community approve it first. For over 2k editor the approval is immediate, but you get notified that your answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks everyone. That is all good information. I assume the underlying answer is if the person who edited your post has over 2k points then you either have to change it back or leave it alone.

Comment: Yes, and if the user revert back after you, he should not in your case, but generally speaking you flag the post, and you can come back there to report. The moderator can stop the edit war and warn the user. but it's like EEAA suggest, it's a per-case basic in such case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By philosophy an design there is no private direct communications channel between users of the site.

You could leave a public comment addressed to `@username` under the answer that was edited and that will pop up as a notification when `username` next visits the site.

As @yagmoth555 pointed out, it is quite possible that you either missed the notification that an answer of yours was edited because the community was quite active and already approved the change, or the edit was made by a high-rep user and effective immediately. Regardless, as far as I know as the author of an answer as you can always select the revision history of your own answers and from there you should have the ability to revert changes, regardless of the [edit privilege](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit).

If it turns into a tug-of-war between the editor and yourself please come to Meta of flag for moderator intervention.